about be about something
Are these pairs of sentences equal to each other?

I am stupid about executions = I don't understand anything about executions.
I am good about lying = I can lie well.
I am bad about cooking = I can't cook well.


What do you mean by this?

@sundowner I am back to learning, maybe it is a wrong usage. I mean one side of 1,2,3 are equal to the other side or not?

Ah, so you are asking if those three equations hold? I guess more or less yes in the sense that they will be understood. But as for 2 and 3, it is more commonly "good/bad at".

@sundowner thanks.

A better equivalent would be good at lying and bad at cooking. (Oh, I see Sundowner has already said that!) Saying that you are 'good about lying' could mean that you think you are 'good' because you don't tell lies. "I am bad about cooking" could mean that you buy a lot of ready-prepared meals, or avoid taking your turn to cook.

@KateBunting it is interesting, thanks.
